# Sum values of similar keys inside two nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have nested dictionary like this:

```
data = {
    "2010":{
            'A':2,
            'B':3,
            'C':5,
            'D':-18,
        },
    "2011":{
            'A':1,
            'B':2,
            'C':3,
            'D':1,
        },
    "2012":{
            'A':1,
            'B':2,
            'C':4,
            'D':2
        }
    }
```

In my case, i need to sum all values based on its similar keys in every year, from 2010 till 2012..
So the result i expected should be like this:

```
data = {'A':4,'B':7, 'C':12, 'D':-15}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
reduce(lambda x, y: dict((k, v + y[k]) for k, v in x.iteritems()), data.values())
```

**Result**

```
{'A': 4, 'B': 7, 'C': 12, 'D': -15}
```

Comment: This is very hacky and unmaintainable, I don't think stackoverflow should become "who code golfs the best". Even someone with a lot of knowledge in Python has to take a good look before understanding  this. Less code =/= better code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter()` (works only for positive values!):

```
In [17]: from collections import Counter
In [18]: sum((Counter(d) for d in data.values()), Counter())
Out[18]: Counter({'C': 12, 'B': 7, 'A': 4, 'D': 3})
```

Note that based on python documentation `Counter` is designed only for use cases with positive values:

> The multiset methods are designed only for use cases with positive values. The inputs may be negative or zero, but only outputs with positive values are created. There are no type restrictions, but the value type needs to support addition, subtraction, and comparison.
>   The `elements()` method requires integer counts. It ignores zero and negative counts.

So if you want to get a comprehensive result you can do the summation manually. The `collections.defaultdict()` is a good way for getting around this problem:

```
In [28]: from collections import defaultdict

In [29]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [30]: for sub in data.values():
   ....:     for i, j in sub.items():
   ....:         d[i] += j
   ....:         

In [31]: d
Out[31]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'D': -15, 'A': 4, 'C': 12, 'B': 7})
```

Comment: What is happening in `In [20]`?

Comment: @RahulKP Interesting point! it should be 15. Let me check again.

Comment: **-1**: This looks nice and compact, **but is not correct**. `Counter` class defines `__add__(..)` to update with the result only when it is positive. See: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L705

Comment: 4 down vote still after update! :-) Is there anything still wrong with my answer?